# JavaScript error: SyntaxError: return not in function on line 22

Tags: javascript

**I was just messing around as a new javascript programmer and decided to make a bank-like withdraw/deposit program, and I came out with this error. I know it's not the best looking but, I try:)**

Couldn't find a way to post my code here, I tried Ctrl+k, but no success. I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/3Ji4tSn9

Comment: use jsfiddle.net to show your code

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to test it out fully, but comparing a string to an array is probably not what you want, try `str.toLowerCase() == "yes"` and simialr

Answer (score 3):

```
return('Have a good day!');
```

Exactly what the error says, you have a `return` that is not inside a `function`.

Did you maybe mean `alert('Have a good day!');`, judging by the rest of the code?